# Hash incorrectly tracking counts, runtime long

Tags: perl, hash, bioinformatics

I am working on a program in Perl and my output is wrong and taking forever to process. The code is meant to take in a large DNA sequence file, read through it in 15 letter increments (kmers), stepping forward 1 position at a time. I'm supposed to enter the kmer sequences into a hash, with their value being the number of incidences of that kmer- meaning each key should be unique and when a duplicate is found, it should increase the count for that particular kmer. I know from my Prof. expected output file, that I have too many lines, so it is allowing duplicates and not counting correctly. It's also running 5+ minutes, so I have to Ctrl+C to escape. When I go look at kmers.txt, the file is at least written and formatted correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

# countKmers.pl
# Open file /scratch/Drosophila/dmel-2L-chromosome-r5.54.fasta
# Identify all k-mers of length 15, load them into a hash
# and count the number of occurences of each k-mer. Each
# unique k-mer and its' count will be written to file
# kmers.txt

#Create an empty hash
my %kMersHash = ();

#Open a filehandle for the output file kmers.txt
unless ( open ( KMERS, ">", "kmers.txt" ) ) {
    die $!;
}

#Call subroutine to load Fly Chromosome 2L
my $sequenceRef = loadSequence("/scratch/Drosophila/dmel-2L-chromosome-r5.54.fasta");

my $kMer      = 15;    #Set the size of the sliding window

my $stepSize  = 1;     #Set the step size

for (

    #The sliding window's start position is 0
    my $windowStart = 0;

    #Prevent going past end of the file
    $windowStart <= ( length($$sequenceRef) - $kMer );

    #Advance the window by the step size
    $windowStart += $stepSize

    )

{

    #Get the substring from $windowStart for length $kMer
    my $kMerSeq = substr( $$sequenceRef, $windowStart, $kMer );

#Call the subroutine to iterate through the kMers
    processKMers($kMerSeq);

}

sub processKMers {

    my ($kMerSeq) = @_;

    #Initialize $kCount with at least 1 occurrence  
    my $kCount = 1;

    #If the key already exists, the count is  
    #increased and changed in the hash
    if ( not exists $kMersHash{$kMerSeq} ) {

            #The hash key=>value is loaded: kMer=>count
            $kMersHash{$kMerSeq} = $kCount;
    }

    else {

            #Increment the count 
            $kCount ++;

            #The hash is updated 
            $kMersHash{$kMerSeq} = $kCount;
    }

    #Print out the hash to filehandle KMERS
    for (keys %kMersHash) {
            print KMERS $_, "\t", $kMersHash{$_}, "\n";
    }
}

sub loadSequence {

    #Get my sequence file name from the parameter array
    my ($sequenceFile) = @_;

    #Initialize my sequence to the empty string
    my $sequence = "";

    #Open the sequence file
    unless ( open( FASTA, "<", $sequenceFile ) ) {
            die $!;
    }

    #Loop through the file line-by-line
    while (<FASTA>) {

            #Assign the line, which is in the default 
            #variable to a named variable for readability.
            my $line = $_;

            #Chomp to get rid of end-of-line characters
            chomp($line);

            #Check to see if this is a FASTA header line
            if ( $line !~ /^>/ ) {

                    #If it's not a header line append it 
                    #to my sequence
                    $sequence .= $line;
            }

    }

    #Return a reference to the sequence
    return \$sequence;
}
```

Comment: You are processing/outputing for every step.  You probably want to go through the steps first, and then output your hash.  You can simplify your counting by just doing `$kMersHash{$kMerSeq}++;` since perl will auto-vivify (create if it doesn't exist) your hash key.

Comment: I know it has to be something in my processKMers subroutine that is duplicating and being inefficient, I just can't figure out what.

Comment: It is because you are `print`ing the keys every time you call `processKMers` which is for every step.  Move the printing logic out of the subroutine and do it just once, after the entire string has been processed.

Comment: @xxfelixxx So are you saying I could take out my if else entirely and just increment?

Comment: Yes.  Here is a good article about it: https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/04/understand-autovivification/

Comment: I've moved the printing to immediately after the processKMers subroutine call, in the main section....  unfortunately I left it still running at over 5 min now.

Comment: How long is your string (bytes/Mb/Gb) ?  Are you running out of memory?

Comment: It's a big file. It's something I'm grabbing from my school's server, so no sure exact size. The expected output is 20,938,309 kmers, but I'm getting 600 million+.

Comment: If you are processing something larger (think string length, plus storage for the hash) than your available memory, the program will grind to a halt until it runs out of memory, then it will exit.  If that is the case, you will need to rethink your processing strategy, likely using temporary files as intermediate steps.

Comment: The current code is going to output all kmers, including those that are only seen once.  Maybe you only want to print them out only if they show up more than N times?

Comment: The expected output file we're allowed to compare against includes kmers with only 1 occurrence. Something else is tripping it up, or maybe it isn't supposed to overlap, ie stepsize = 15, but the directions didn't read that way.

Comment: I would recommend testing with a short sequence and checking that the output is what you expect, before trying to process the whole thing.  The development/testing will be much faster for you.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and time!

Comment: Good luck with your assignment!

Comment: Glad to see you have `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: A similar question was posed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6338276/sunny) and it may be of some help.

Comment: A bit late, but [jellyfish](http://www.genome.umd.edu/jellyfish.html) looks like a likely solution to finding kmers (though I think it only works on Linux systems) Also [here](http://www.cbcb.umd.edu/software/jellyfish/) and [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/17436/#17442).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write your application. The `processKMers` subroutine boils down to just incrementing a hash element, so I've removed that. I've also altered the identifiers to be match the `snake_case` that is more usual in Perl code, and I didn't see any point in `load_sequence` returning a reference to the sequence so I've changed it to return the string itself

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use constant FASTA_FILE => '/scratch/Drosophila/dmel-2L-chromosome-r5.54.fasta';
use constant KMER_SIZE  => 15;
use constant STEP_SIZE  => 1;

my $sequence = load_sequence( FASTA_FILE );

my %kmers;

for (my $offset = 0;
        $offset + KMER_SIZE <= length $sequence;
        $offset += STEP_SIZE ) {

    my $kmer_seq = substr $sequence, $start, KMER_SIZE;

    ++$kmers{$kmer_seq};
}

open my $out_fh, '>', 'kmers.txt' or die $!;

for ( keys %kmers ) {
    printf $out_fh "%s\t%d\n", $_, $kmers{$_};
}

sub load_sequence {

    my ( $sequence_file ) = @_;

    my $sequence = "";

    open my $fh, '<', $sequence_file or die $!;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        next if /^>/;
        chomp;
        $sequence .= $_;
    }

    return $sequence;
}
```

Here's a neater way to increment a hash element without using `++` on the hash directly

```
my $n;

if ( exists $kMersHash{$kMerSeq} ) {
    $n = $kMersHash{$kMerSeq};
}
else {
    $n = 0;
}

++$n;
$kMersHash{$kMerSeq} = $n;
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I'm only 10 weeks into learning Perl, so the comments and code style reflect that. The variables you've altered to constants aren't appropriate as kmers differ from query to query and the code is meant to be reusable.

Comment: @Michelle_M:  The values I've declared as constants are constant only within one run of the program. They are no more fixed than your own `$kMer` and `$stepSize`.

Comment: I understand, it's just that the accompanying lecture indicated we shouldn't make them constants.

Comment: @Michelle_M: Ah. If this is a homework question then you should have said so. You would have got a very different style of answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was implied in my question where I mentioned my Professor. Just trying to figure this stuff out from a newbie perspective.

Comment: @Michelle_M: Sorry, I didn't realise that *Prof.* was short for *Professor*. I'm largely ignorant with anything other than mathematics and computer science, so abbreviations could mean anything after *kmers* were mentioned!

Comment: @Michelle_M: I've added to my answer to show how to more neatly increment a hash element without using `++` on it directly.

Answer (score -1):

Everything looks fine in your code besides `processKMers`.  The main issues:

- `$kCount` is not persistent between calls to `processKMers`, so in your else statement, `$kCount` will always be 2
- You are printing every time you call `processKMers`, which is what is slowing you down.  Printing frequently slows down your process significantly, you should wait until the end of your program and print once.

Keeping your code mostly the same:

```
sub processKMers {

    my ($kMerSeq) = @_;

    if ( not exists $kMersHash{$kMerSeq} ) {
            $kMersHash{$kMerSeq} = 1;
    }
    else {
            $kMersHash{$kMerSeq}++;
    }
}
```

Then you want to move your print logic to immediately after your for-loop.

Comment: Thank you for leaving my beginner-style code intact. As I noted with the other answerer, I'm only 10 weeks into learning Perl. Is there a more "remedial" way to increment the hash? We haven't learned using ++ with a hash.

Comment: You can use `++` with any scalar, but it is the same as `$kMersHash{$kMerSeq} + $kMersHash{$kMerSeq} + 1;`.

Comment: Er - that's supposed to say `$kMersHash{$kMerSeq} = $kMersHash{$kMerSeq} + 1;`.  Guess I can't edit comments.